# Using NVL with JOIN not returning the default value if null

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I have this query, just changed tables and columns name.

```
SELECT COM.NAME,
COM.SURNAME,
NVL(COM.ACCOUNT, -1) AS ACCOUNT,
(SELECT NVL(BA.ACCOUNT_ID, '-1')
FROM TABLE2 BA
WHERE BA.ACCOUNT_ID = COM.ACCOUNT_ID) AS ACCOUNT_ID
FROM TABLE1 COM
WHERE COM.UNIQUE_DNI = 123123;
```

Search show the registry as:

```
NAME  ACCOUNT  ACCOUNT_ID
qwe   -1
```

Im trying to make the -1 appear when BA.ACCOUNT_ID is null but with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just use an explicit `left join`:

```
SELECT COM.NAME, COM.SURNAME, COALESCE(COM.ACCOUNT, -1) AS ACCOUNT,
       COALESCE(BA.CCOUNT_DI, '-1') AS ACCOUNT_ID
FROM TABLE1 COM LEFT JOIN
     TABLE2 BA
     ON BA.ACCOUNT_ID = COM.ACCOUNT_ID
WHERE COM.UNIQUE_DNI = 123123;
```

Your problem though is that the `NVL()` is *inside* the subquery.  It needs to be applied to the results of the subquery.  I prefer `COALESCE()` over `NVL()` simply because `COALESCE()` is ANSI/ISO standard.

Comment: Thanks a lot,  got it! In this case I have to apply the COALESCE() to the result of the query.